# Of vs same as in sentence

Tags: prepositions

> There must be one more same piece as this .
>
> There must be one more piece of this .

While playing lego , I know that there two same pieces . But I couldn’t find one of them. Ithis case which one should I use “ same as” or“ of” . I mean which sentence above is correct?

Answer (score 2):

*Same* used before a noun is always definite: *the same X*, or less commonly *that/this/those/these same X*. So *one more same X* is at least not idiomatic, and I'm not sure it's grammatical.

But it can be used independently, following the noun it qualifies, so

> There must be one more piece the same as this.

is fine, and the normal way to express what you are trying to say.

Similarly, *two same pieces* is not normal, but *two pieces the same* is fine.

Your second case is problematical in a different way.

> There must be one more piece of this.

is grammatical, but sounds odd in this context because *a piece of* normally means "a part of a whole", whereas I think you mean "a piece **like** this". You could also say "a piece of this type", or "a piece of this shape", and then the expressed "type" or "shape" would override the usual meaning of "a piece of".

Answer (score 1):

This is how I might express what you are trying to say:

> There must be one more piece *just like this one*.

If you want to sound a bit more formal, you could use:

> There must be one more piece *identical to this one*.

Also, some might find the use of *must* a little awkward in this context. We could express that part of this thought as follows:

> I know there is one more piece just like this one.